# Spark Loading Data from Azure Data Lake Store - Py4JJavaError: NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to load data in Spark 2.3.1 from ADLS using the following:

```
moviesfileAdls = "adl://xxxxxx.azuredatalakestore.net/Data/movies.csv"

dfMovies = spark.read.format("csv") \
                .option("header", "true") \
                .option("delimiter",",") \
                .load(moviesfileAdls)
```

The setup:  Hadoop-3.1.1 running on the same box as spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7.  In hdfs, I am able to get the file using the following command:

```
hadoop distcp adl://xxxxxx.azuredatalakestore.net/Data/movies.csv /user/hadoop/movies
```

The above command successfully copies the file into local HDFS so I believe the hadoop setup is OK.

However, when I try to run the spark.read.format("csv") command, I am getting the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o54.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.reloadExistingConfigurations()V
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlConfKeys.addDeprecatedKeys(AdlConfKeys.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem.<clinit>(AdlFileSystem.java:98)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried adding the ADLS jars directly in spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.jars /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.3.1.jar, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-azure-datalake-3.1.1.jar
```

HADOOP_CLASSPATH refers to the folder where the jars are located according to the spark user:

```
spark@xxxxx:~$ echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.